java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source when trying to open an Excel file with Apache POI
I am working on a Groovy project where I need to load an Excel file using Apache POI. The file is provided by a third party, and I encounter an issue when trying to open it directly. If I manually open the file in Excel and save it, the file becomes usable, but I want to automate this process in my code.

    java.io.IOException: Failed to read zip entry source
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:103)
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.OPCPackage.open(OPCPackage.java:324)
  at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:185)
  at org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(WorkbookFactory.java:144)
  at com.apsec.groovy.job.util.POIUtil.openWorkbook(POIUtil.groovy:60)
  at com.apsec.groovy.job.axiom.AxiomAToMReportV2Load.run(AxiomAToMReportV2Load.groovy:213)
  at com.apsec.groovy.job.AbstractJob.run(AbstractJob.groovy:67)
  at com.apsec.groovy.job.developer.LocalEnvironment.run(LocalEnvironment.groovy:106)
  at com.apsec.groovy.job.axiom.AxiomAToMReportV2Load.main(AxiomAToMReportV2Load.groovy:359)
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 1053 bytes)
  at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.readEnd(ZipInputStream.java:384)
  at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:196)
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile$ThresholdInputStream.read(ZipSecureFile.java:219)
  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107)
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource$FakeZipEntry.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:132)
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.<init>(ZipInputStreamZipEntrySource.java:56)
  at org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.ZipPackage.<init>(ZipPackage.java:100)
  ... 8 more


I am using Apache POI version 3.16.
Here is the openWorkbook method I am using:
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.util.ZipSecureFile
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import java.io.File
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.io.FileOutputStream
import java.io.IOException
import java.io.FileNotFoundException

@Slf4j
static Workbook openAndRepairWorkbook(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidFormatException {
    FileInputStream fis = null
    Workbook workbook = null
    File repairedFile = new File(file.getParent(), "repaired_" + file.getName())

    try {
        if (!file.exists() || !file.canRead()) {
            log.error("File does not exist or cannot be read: {}", file.getAbsolutePath())
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File does not exist or cannot be read: " + file.getAbsolutePath())
        }

        log.info("Attempting to open workbook from file: {}", file.getAbsolutePath())
        fis = new FileInputStream(file)
        ZipSecureFile.setMinInflateRatio(0.0001) // Adjust the zip bomb detection threshold

        try {
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis)
            log.info("Workbook successfully opened.")

            // Save the workbook to a new file to "repair" it
            log.info("Saving workbook to repaired file: {}", repairedFile.getAbsolutePath())
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(repairedFile)
            workbook.write(fos)
            fos.close()
            workbook.close()

            // Reopen the repaired file
            log.info("Reopening the repaired workbook.")
            fis = new FileInputStream(repairedFile)
            workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fis)
            log.info("Repaired workbook successfully opened.")
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            log.error("InvalidFormatException encountered: {}", e.getMessage())
            throw e
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("IOException encountered: {}", e.getMessage())
            throw e
        }
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            try {
                fis.close()
            } catch (IOException e) {
                log.error("Error closing FileInputStream: {}", e.getMessage())
            }
        }
    }
    return workbook
}

What I've Tried
Manual Fix:
If I open the problematic Excel file in Microsoft Excel and simply save it without making any changes, the file can be processed without any issues by my code.
Programmatic Attempt:
I have tried to mimic the manual process programmatically by opening the workbook, saving it to a new file, and then reopening the repaired file using the openAndRepairWorkbook method shown above. However, I still encounter the same error.
What I Need
I would like to find a way to handle this issue programmatically without manually opening and saving the file in Excel. Ideally, I'd like to:
Identify the root cause of the IOException related to the zip entry source.
Implement a solution that allows my code to open, repair, and process the file automatically.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or have any suggestions on how to resolve this? Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Try a newer version of Java because the error is on java.util.zip.ZipInputStream. Another way could be to open the file with some Java zip library that doesn't depend on Java's java.util.zip and if it opens recompress it in a new file that hopefully is more compatible with Java.

do you have a suggestion? of another library? I've tried with TIka with the same results, I need to open this xlsx file :(

Apache POI 3.16 was released back in 2017, what happens if you upgrade to a vaguely recent version?

Recommendations of libraries are off topic in [so].

"Identify the root cause of the IOException": The error and your description: "If I open the problematic Excel file in Microsoft Excel and simply save it without making any changes, the file can be processed without any issues by my code. " says: There is something in the *.xlsx ZIP archive what Excel not would store there. So something else than Excel had created that *.xlsx file and had put something additional in there. We don't know what as you don't told us. To be able to help we would need the *.xlsx file.

Btw.: Are you sure you can trust the source of the *.xlsx file? Could be an attempted attack .

hello @AxelRichter, yes, I can trust the file, it comes from a reputale source, however I can't share it here. I have to work with them in order to generate it with a format that I could ingest, but I was trying to work this workaround and receive it with teh current one

1/ open file with notepad and validate that it starts with PK. 2/ try to unzip xlsx with code - in groovy you could do it with new groovy.ant.AntBuilder().unzip(src: 'my.xlsx', dest: './target') - any errors? 3/ ideally - you should provide a file example to be able to answer your question - otherwise we are just guessing here.

XLSX files are zipped XML files.  So if you rename the suffix xlsx -> zip you could open it up in Winzip or other zip software and look at the contents of the file.  You can also use that program to figure out some facts like format (Zip64, etc)  Maybe a file in there has a 0 bytes entry when it should be populated with more data (like it says 0 bytes, but there are actual bytes in the file).  That's what the error message seems to indicate.   You need to start gathering facts about the file that might help you understand what's wrong with it.
You may also have hit this bug:
Stream Zip files: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid entry size (expected 0 but got 419 bytes)
Zip64 files under 4gb hit this defect from time to time so check if this zip file is zip64 possibly.  And see what JDK version you are using.  Some of Java8 is susceptible to this bug, and others are not.
This all hinges on the structure of that zip file so you're going to have to dig into the details of the file format to figure it out.
